# Regular expression to disallow empty string and comma

Tags: regex, go, swagger, nsregularexpression, qregularexpression

I'm trying to write regular expression to restrict empty string and comma inside a string

example:

```
string = "" # not allowed
s = "ab c!@#)(*&^%$#~" # allowed
s = "sfsfsf,sdfsdf" # not allowed
```

The intention of this regexp is to do a pattern matching in swagger documentation like this property: `type: string pattern: "^[0-9A-Za-z_]+$" value: type: object`

I tried this regular expression `^(?!\s*$)[^,]*$` but it is not supported inside swagger doc and I get this error in golang code for this regular expression:

> `` invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?! ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need a look ahead.

Just remove that lookahead expression and change `*` to `+` which will require at least one character and simplify your regex to `^[^,]+$`

Let me know if that works or if you have more conditions.

Edit:

Considering @JvdV's comment (and he seems right), you can use following regex,

```
^\s*([^,\s]+\s*)+$
```

This will match if there is at least one non whitespace character and whole string will be rejected if there is even a single occurrence of a comma

[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/T4yMWC/1)

Edit1:

To avoid catastrophic backtracking, the regex can be simplified as following,

```
^\s*[^,\s][^,]*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - Match start of input
- `\s*` - Optionally match any whitespaces
- `[^,\s]` - Match at least one character other than comma and whitespace
- `[^,]*` - Can be followed by any character other than comma zero or more times
- `$` - Match end of string

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V1G5qU/1)

Edit2: For avoiding leading/trailing whitespaces, you can use this regex,

```
^[^\s,]([^,]*[^\s,])?$
```

[Demo avoiding leading/trailing whitespaces](https://regex101.com/r/N4CG1J/1)

Comment: By the looks of ops attempt he want to avoid an empty string or rather a string with just whitespace. Maybe `^[^,]*[^,\s][^,]*$` is more comprehensive.

Comment: @JvdV: Yes you seem right. Updated answer to take care empty string to not match

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi this will cause catastrophic backtracking if string is big and comma comes at the end   https://regex101.com/r/Ff01w6/1

Comment: @ShashankBhat: Yes, overly nesting can be avoided and you can use `^\s*[^,\s][^,]*$` regex. Let me update answer.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thanks for the answer. Just to make it much simpler, `^[^\s,][^,]*[^\s,]$`  This will not allow trailing whitespaces. Correct me if Im wrong

Comment: @ShashankBhat: In that case, your regex will require minimum two characters to match, where as a single character should match too. If you don't want to allow leading/trailing whitespaces, then go for this regex `^[^\s,]([^,]*[^\s,])?$` [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/N4CG1J/1) and this matches just single character too.